# Jquery Scrolltop to bottom in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: scrolltop

I would like to create a button, when click , the modal will appear and then scroll to the bottom :

my button code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Launch demo scrolltop to bottom

my modal code :

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla

       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
b    la bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
   bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla
       bla bla
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla 
bla bla

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How? I read about scrolltop but i did not understand how the scrolltop would works in modal dialog box .

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vm0qr8r5/) what you want ?

Comment: hi, sorry, i already update your fiddle link , it should be has scroll inside the modal-body, please check it , i would like scroll to bottom